# windows xp 2 GB missing hard drive space

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-xp

I've got an odd problem with a machine that has a old windows XP installed on it (changing the OS is sadly not possible for that machine).

The hard drive is a 90 GB drive (84 useable). So far so good.

Now when I tried to clean up the contents I enabled seeing all hidden files in the windows explorer, made a clean hard drive command on the hard drive properties and then went through all the main folders in c:\ and noted down the sizes to see where I could best get started.

So far so good with only one exception......the hard drive says that 11,7 GB of space are used (properties) but I only come up to 9,52 GB including the pagefile in C:\ when I mark all in C:\ and use properties) as 72,3 of the 84,0 GB are empty.

So my question is where could those 2,18 GB of missing disk space be at?
(already did a chkdsk but it came up inconclussive and I'm running out of ideas now because of that)

Comment: You have hidden files and system files visible? You can use software such as `WinDirStat` to try and visualise where your space is used up.

Comment: @jono yes I have them visible. I clicked on C:\ and then marked all content of the C:\ folder and clicked properties (as I'm logged in as admin on that machine the win explorer should have listed all used up space thus there). Doesn't windirstat do the same in essence as the windows explorer? (at least from what I read up)

Comment: Sure, similar, but it *could* provide more information. We currently have nothing to go on, really. For all we know, 2GB of temp files may have been there which aren't now. Almost impossible for us to guess :)

Comment: shouldn't those temp files be then either taken into account as I see the hidden files either in the properties of c:\?  or when I say clear the recycle bin?